# How to load a DatePicker value into a UITextField present on another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, datepicker, uitextfield

I have two ViewControllers in which the DatePicker is present on one ViewController and the Textfield where the date is supposed to load(from the DatePicker) is present on another ViewController.
I would like to know how to load the values from this DatePicker to the UITextField which is present on another ViewController.

```
- (IBAction)datePickerChanged:(id)sender {
ViewController *modal = [[ViewController alloc]init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy hh:mm a"];
modal.dateTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",     [dateFormatter stringFromDate:_datePicker.date]];
}
```

I have created an object called "model" and tried it with "dateTextField" , but it shows error.

Comment: can you please show me the error?

Comment: property 'dataTextField' not found on object of type 'ViewController'.But I have imported the ViewController and an object is already present over there.

Comment: Check you created property on .h file?

Comment: It is a bad design to access IBOutlet of one view controller from another view controller.

Comment: IBOutlets are not assigned until the view is loaded. This means that if the view controller is allocated but has not been put on the screen yet, the IBOutlets are still nil.

Comment: @Exception 
I have a textfield and a button in a viewcontroller.When i click the button,a popup shows with datepicker in it(its another view controller).When the value is changed on that datepicker ,it must be shown in the textfield. So the popup is a different viewcontroller.I have to access the valueChanged from the viewcontroller where datepicker is present to another viewcontroller where textfield is present.

Comment: @Akhil, You can do this using Delegates.

Comment: @Exception Can you please elaborate?

Comment: It can do by using local notifications also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

Create property of textfield on another view controller - in `.h` file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *dateTextField;
```

Set outlet properly

Then, in first view controller where date picker is present, in the `valueChanged` method of date picker get the property of text field from another view controller and set value to it.

```
- (IBAction) datePickerChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender
{
    ViewController *modal = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy hh:mm a"];
    modal.dateTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:_datePicker.date]]; 
}
```

And it works.

Comment: I have created a property for textfield named 'dateTextField' in first ViewController.Then added in the valueChanged part in second ViewController where date picker is present.But it shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller with DatePicker, In **.h** file add

```
@protocol DismissPopoverDelegate <NSObject>

    - (void) dismissPopover:(NSString *)selectedate;
@end
```

And add a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<DismissPopoverDelegate> popDelegate
```

In **.m**

```
- (IBAction) datePickerChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy hh:mm a"];
    NSString* date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:_datePicker.date]];

    [self.popDelegate dismissPopover: date];
}
```

Now in your viewcontroller with **text field**, In **.h** file

```
 @interface YourViewController:UIViewController<DismissPopoverDelegate>
```

In **.m** file, implement:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad{

      YourfirstviewControllerobject.popDelegate=self;
}
-(void) dismissPopover:(NSString*) selectedDate{

     self.dateTextField.text=selectedDate;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this because you can't update one controller uielement by another view controller. but you can can use string property for this  and set on the second view controller viewdidload

Comment: This is wrong. You can update another view controller's UIElement by setting a protocol with a delegate method like DidChoseDate that you call once the date has been chosen in the date picker. You then declare the DidChoseDate delegate method in your other VC that you set as the delegate and have the UIElement udpated

Answer (score 0):

You can create protocol on you datePicker's controller class and same can implement in your textfield's controller class.